# Collecting objects that are not necessarly assigned to any variables/constants

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Objects that are not assigned to any variable/constant disappear immediately (under normal circumstance). In the following, the string `"foo"` is not captured by `ObjectSpace.each_object(String)` in the third line:

```
strings = ObjectSpace.each_object(String).to_a
  "foo"
ObjectSpace.each_object(String).to_a - strings # => []
```

Is it possible to capture objects that are not necessarly assigned to any variables/constants or part of any variables/constants? I am particularly interested in capturing strings. The relevant domain can be a file, or a block. I expect something like the following:

```
capture_all_strings do
  ...
  "a"
  s = "b"
  @s = "c"
  @@s = "d"
  S = "e"
  %q{f}
  ...
end
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Comment: what does just `ObjectSpace.each_object(String).to_a` return?

Comment: There's an issue here in that String literals are instantiated at compile time. So that rules out a whole family of tricks where you would add the new objects to a pool by modifying `String.new` or something similar.

Comment: I get that even if the object is assigned to a variable it is not captured by `ObjectSpace.each_object(String)` (e.g. if you changed the second line in your first example to be `a = "foo"`) it seems from your question that this is not the expected behaviour, is that right?

Comment: your `strings` array already includes `"foo"`, that's why it seems to be missing :-)

Comment: Mike, Stefan That seems to be right. I did not realize that, and that is unexpected to me. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby creates the string instances when parsing your file. Here's an example: the string

```
"aaa #{123} zzz"
```

is parsed as:

```
$ ruby --dump=parsetree -e '"aaa #{123} zzz"'
###########################################################
## Do NOT use this node dump for any purpose other than  ##
## debug and research.  Compatibility is not guaranteed. ##
###########################################################

# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 1)
# +- nd_tbl: (empty)
# +- nd_args:
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body:
#     @ NODE_DSTR (line: 1)
#     +- nd_lit: "aaa "
#     +- nd_next->nd_head:
#     |   @ NODE_EVSTR (line: 1)
#     |   +- nd_body:
#     |       @ NODE_LIT (line: 1)
#     |       +- nd_lit: 123
#     +- nd_next->nd_next:
#         @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1)
#         +- nd_alen: 1
#         +- nd_head:
#         |   @ NODE_STR (line: 1)
#         |   +- nd_lit: " zzz"
#         +- nd_next:
#             (null node)
```

There are two string literals at the parser stage, `"aaa "` and `" zzz"`:

```
#     +- nd_lit: "aaa "
#     ...
#         |   +- nd_lit: " zzz"
```

Inspecting `ObjectSpace` confirms that these strings have been instantiated:

```
$ ruby -e '"aaa #{123} zzz"; ObjectSpace.each_object(String) { |s| p s }' | egrep "aaa|zzz"
"\"aaa \#{123} zzz\"; ObjectSpace.each_object(String) { |s| p s }\n"
"aaa 123 zzz"
" zzz"
"aaa "
```

So unless you are creating a new string instance (e.g. by assigning the string literal to a variable) you can't detect the string creation. It's already there when the code is being executed.